# Ignoring/blocking SIGPIPE signals in multi-threaded linux program

Tags: unix, pthreads, signals, sigkill, sigpipe

I have the following situation:
Thread 1:
Forks a child and the child, say A in turn forks again and executes a process. B

Thread 2:
Listens for commands over a Unix Domain Socket and kills the process, B that has been forked by child, A in Thread 1
Respond to caller that it has killed the child

I want to ignore SIGPIPE for Thread 2 as I do not want the program to crash when client has closed the socket. So i tried doing this using

```
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGPIPE);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
```

Doing this helps block SIGPIPE but it also blocks the ability of the thread 1 to send SIGKILL to the child.

I also tried using the below in main function before creating threads

```
signal(SIG_IGN, SIGPIPE);
```

and
    send with MSG_NOSIGNAL flag in socket.

This doesnt help my scenario with SIGKILL as well. Any idea how to ignore safely the SIGPIPE in a multi-threaded condition like above with forks and execs and SIGKILLs sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, I found out the solution to it. I had to do 
`pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);`
after the each fork() calls and before exec() in the grand child. This caused SIGKILL to not get blocked.